# How to know the version of the installed Dropbox application?

Tags: windows-7, windows, dropbox, version

I've look through the Prefences box and the notification icon's context menu but found nowhere to see the current version of the application.

Do you see it elsewhere?

My OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hover your cursor over the Dropbox icon in the tray and a pop up should appear telling you the version of Dropbox you are running.

[image]

Comment: Nothing beats simplicity!

Answer (score 6):

Look in the Add/Remove Program section in Control Panel
[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you're on a Mac: Applications → Dropbox → Select it → `⌘+i`.

Edit: sorry, I did not see you are on Windows. I'll leave the answer, anyway.